# ASP.NET radiobuttonlist onclientclick

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I've noticed there is no OnClientClick() property for the radiobuttonlist in the ASP.NET control set. Is this a purposeful omissiong on Microsoft's part?
Anyway, I've tried to add OnClick to the radio button list like so:

```
For Each li As ListItem In rblSearch.Items
    li.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:alert('jon');")
Next
```

But alas, it doesn't work. I've even checked the source in firebug, and there is no javascript shown in the radiobuttonlist.  Does anyone know how to get this very simple thing working? I'm using ASP.NET control adpaters so don't know if that has anything to do with it.

(I wish asp.net/javascript would just work out the box!!!)

Comment: Show us more of your code.  Are you binding your list items to the radiobuttonlist in the backend, or declaratively in your aspx?

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091405-1.aspx Read section on "why attributes cannot be applied to listitems of a list control"

Comment: no its just a plain old static list. I think the answer below is the answer. I don't think the checkbox list attributes get rendered at all.

Answer (score 30):

I found I could just add a onclick attribute to the RadioButtonList and it would fire the javascript client side as expected.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" onclick="alert('RadioButtonListSelectChange');">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"/>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"/>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You could then write a client script that could determine the currently selected list item.

Comment: I tried this in FireFox but found that the onclick event is fired twice (presumably once for each list item).

Comment: @EdGraham, I had the same experience, but I think it has to do with clicking on the Label for the radio button. The event is fired only once when clicking on the radio input, but fired twice when clicking on the label. Which makes this answer almost useless.

Answer (score 3):

The onclick attribute function very good in ListItem object. Try in this way:

```
li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showDiv()")
```

That function to me.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer but a few weird observations on the other suggestions.  I'll preface this by saying this is a RadioButtonList in an ASP.Net 4.0 app with RepeatDirection=Vertical

1) Adding onclick='myJsFunction(this);' attributes to the ListItems worked fine for me *except* after a different item on the page causes a post back (a button action for example), the attributes on the ListItems **don't get rendered** in the result of the postback.  They get rendered to start, but not when there's a button action.  Go figure.

2) Apparently our legacy code was relying on some murky, less than canonical behavior on the RadioButtonList/ListItem that gets very muddy on postback.  If you put an **id** attribute on a ListItem, ASP.Net 2.0+ will add a **span** tag around the radio button and put your id value there.  If you add an **onclick** attribute on it, that will go on the radio button - at least when Page.IsPostBack == false.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList  ID="proceedChoice" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
    <asp:ListItem id="Close_Case_Y" Value="Y" onclick="SelectResolveType(this);" Text="I want to close this case."  runat="server" />
    <asp:ListItem id="Close_Case_N" Value="N" onclick="SelectResolveType(this);" Text="I want to cancel this and start over."  runat="server" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

renders as

```
<table id="...proceedChoice" border="0">
<tr>
    <td><span id="Close_Case_Y"><input id="..._proceedChoice_0" type="radio" value="Y" onclick="SelectResolveType(this);" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_0">I want to close this case.</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><span id="Close_Case_N"><input id="..._proceedChoice_1" type="radio" value="N" onclick="SelectResolveType(this);" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_1">I want to cancel this case and start over.</label></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

After a postback from some other button, though the same template renders as

```
<table id="...proceedChoice" border="0">
<tr>
    <td><input id="..._proceedChoice_0" type="radio" value="Y" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_0">I want to close this case.</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="..._proceedChoice_1" type="radio" value="N" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_1">I want to cancel this case and start over.</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But here's where it gets really weird: if you tack on other attributes to ListItem other than id and onclick, **just those** attributes get preserved.  For example if I add hidden="hidden" to one of the ListItems, it gets rendered like this after postback

```
<table id="...proceedChoice" border="0">
<tr>
    <td><span hidden="hidden"><input id="..._proceedChoice_0" type="radio" value="Y" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_0">I want to close this case.</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="..._proceedChoice_1" type="radio" value="N" /><label for="..._proceedChoice_1">I want to cancel this case and start over.</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Finding posts about how ListItems only stash the text and value in viewstate, so that's why attributes get lost on postback which makes sense, but I'm still puzzled why an attribute like hidden would be preserved on postback then...

Comment: Also used Reflector to find that the 4guys RenderItem() override suggestion is now incorporated into the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a list control, there isn't a OnClientClick event. Either use a postback (SelectedIndexChange) or write javascript to grab the click for each radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
            foreach (PlaceType t in query.ToList())
        {

            ListItem li = new ListItem(@"<img src=""" + t.ImageRelativePath + @"""/><br/>" + t.PlaceTypeText, t.PlaceTypeID.ToString());
            li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:placeTypeChange('" + t.ImageRelativePath + "')");
            rblPlaceTypes.Items.Add(li);
        }
```

So in there I'm

a) Iterating over the results of a EF query.
b) Creating a new list item, and adding it to my radio button list (rblPlaceTypes).
c) The constructor is putting an image in so that displays.
d) the li.Attributs.Add is putting the javascript wireup in.